# Creating two lists and compare the matching

Tags: python, string, output

I have two list of numbers but I need a evaluate and see if any numbers match then out put the # of matching numbers.

```
import random
matches = random.sample (range(1, 20), 5),random.sample (range(1, 20), 5)
```

Comment: What does your code demonstrate?

Comment: Please define your problem more clearly. I guess you know how to create a second list (of random numbers?) - do you want to know how to find out if there are duplicates between the two lists? If so, do those duplicates have to be in the same position, or would you consider `[1,2,3,4]` and `[4,3,2,1]` to be wholly duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a set intersection.

```
from random import sample

set_a = set(sample(range(0, 50), 10))
set_b = set(sample(range(0, 50), 10))

print set_a.intersection(set_b) # [3, 4]
print set_a & set_b # sugar for the same thing
```

Comment: it returns                                                   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Comment: @Turner sets != lists. You can convert a list to set (like I do in the example above).

Comment: this is what I have sorry i don't really understand your response.           'import random
matches_a= random.sample(range(1, 20), 5)
matches_b= random.sample(range(1, 20), 5)
print matches_a.intersection(matches_b)
print matches_a & matches_b'

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension one liner:

```
[x for x in list_a if x in list_b]
```

you get the list of items contained in both lists.
to demonstrate all items are found:

```
>>> a = range(10,50)
>>> b = range(10,50)
>>> [x for x in a if x in b]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
```

Comment: this is only returning the highest matching not all...

Comment: should work... post your entire code and lets see.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your code I came up with following code.

```
m = [1,2,3]
n = [3,4,1]
for i in m:
    for j in n:
        if i == j:
            print "matched elements are list1 and list2 are (%s) and (%s)" %(i,j)
        else:
            print "list1 and list2 have unique elements"
```